# Algebraic Geometry: Show that $\overline{X} = Z(\mathcal{I}(X))$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

I am stuck at the following exercise:

> For every $X \in \mathbb{A}^2$ holds $\overline{X} = Z(\mathcal{I}(X))$.

Here are the required definitions:

> (We defined $Z(F)$ for a set $F$ of polynomials as the set of common zeroes of the polynomials in $F$ (i.e. $Z$ is the Variety of $F$) and $\mathcal{I}(X) := \{P \in K[X,Y] : P(x) = 0$ for all $x \in X \subset \mathbb{A}^2\}$, i.e. $\mathcal{I}(A)$ is the vanishing ideal of $X$. When talking about open and closed sets this is always in regards to the Zariski Topology.)

I see that

$$\overline{X} = \bigcap_{\substack{ X \subseteq A \\ A \text{ closed}}} A = \bigcap_{\substack{ X \subseteq A \\ A \text{ algebraic}}} A = \bigcap_{\substack{ F \subseteq K[X,Y] \\ X \subseteq Z(F)}} A.$$

So the part $\supseteq$ is clear since $\mathcal{I}(X) \subset K[X,Y]$ and $X \subset Z(\mathcal{I}(X))$. However, I do not see how to do the part $\subseteq$. Could you please give me hint?

Comment: If $U\subseteq V$ and $V$ is closed, then also $\overline U\subseteq V$ in every topological space, since $\overline U$ is the smallest closed set containing $U$.